# Write a shorter SQL query to table with values is strings with delimiter

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

Data:

[image: 1]

My SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Art], [Count], [Comm], [w]
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    [W] IS NULL
    OR [W] = '104'                                    -- how can this be written shorter?
    OR [W] LIKE '104" & CHR(10) & "%'                 -- value at the begin
    OR [W] LIKE '%" & CHR(10) & "104'                 -- value at the end
    OR [W] LIKE '%" & CHR(10) & "104" & CHR(10) & "%' -- value at the middle
```

Result:

[image: 2]

`LIKE` operator in SQL does not have same power as a regexp :(

I use ADO in Excel VBA.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of Excel sheets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table and post that.

Comment: I did a quick test with Excel using ADO and  `WHERE [W] is null OR [W] Like '%104%'` works for me unless the 2nd picture you posted is the result you want to have. Or do you want not have `104dw` etc. in the result. You marked them in the 1st picture red. For me it's not quite clear what you want to have.

Comment: @Storax, yes it marked red. I do not want to have it values in result.

Comment: @user10186832, chr(10) is defined as a new table row and looks crisp

Comment: Ok, then an SQL expert might have a hint. I would not know how to integrate RegExp into this.

Comment: If you only want records where W contains 104 and no text, check if it is numeric as well. If data and query are in Excel, why do you show Access tag? Don't post images of data, post formatted text table - https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables.

Comment: Oh, wait, you don't want the 1010414 record so only where 104 is a discrete value.  So, without RegExp, what you have may be the best can do.

Comment: I think to use RegExp would have to write a VBA function that could be called by query. Is that shorter and simpler than what you already have? Guess it depends on your point of view. And I know how to do that from Access query object, but not SQL constructed in VBA.

Comment: Can call VBA function from cells and then that column can be retrieved in query and used to filter records.

Comment: have you tried PATINDEX -- Find the position of an email address in the string 'Contact us at email@example.com for assistance.'
SELECT PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}%', 'Contact us at email@example.com for assistance.') AS Position;
-- Output: 16